# Google Maps API v1 to v2 using MapView

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-mapview

I have an application using Google Maps API v1.
I need to make changes but I dont know what to change in Google Maps API v2 to continue using the Map View from v1.

I added the meta-data with the api key as a child of application. And I removed it from the Map View `<com.google.android.maps.MapView`

Its too difficult to use Map Fragment and change everything because there's too much code using Map View.

I found this link but it doesnt seem to help much.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView

Answer (score 2):

> I dont know what to change in Google Maps API v2 to continue using the Map View from v1.

You cannot use the `MapView` from Maps V1. Maps V2 has different classes for this, and while it does have its own widget named `MapView`, the API is different.

> Its too difficult to use Map Fragment and change everything because there's too much code using Map View.

You do not have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

> I found this link but it doesnt seem to help much.

That's mainly because the equivalent of `MapView` (in terms of getting access to the Maps API) is the `GoogleMap` object you can get from the `MapFragment.getMap()`.

Here is the [GoogleMap class reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap?hl=en)